Definite integral $\int_{-1}^1 \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{1-2xt+t^2}\sqrt{1-2xs+s^2}}$ related with Legendre polynomials generating function
Recently, as a math tutor, I was thinking how one could introduce to students the famous Legendre polynomials. One standard way is by the Generating function
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-2xt+t^2}} = \sum_{l=0}^\infty t^l P_l(x)$$
However, by this definition alone, it's not at all obvious to me how one could obtain the orthogonality relation which states
$$\int_{-1}^1 P_l(x)P_{l'}(x) \,\mathrm{d}x = \frac{2}{2l+1}\delta_{ll'}$$
I came up with this solution: Note that now one might hide all the orthogonality relations into one single formula with parameters $t,s\in(-1,1)$:
$$\sum_{l,l'=0}^\infty t^l s^{l'} P_l(x)P_{l'}(x) = \int_{-1}^1 \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{1-2xt+t^2}\sqrt{1-2xs+s^2}}$$
If you assume orthogonality, you can set $t=s$ and get the correct normalizing factor $2/(2l+1)$ straight ahead. This has already been answered here: (Orthogonality of Legendre polynomials from generating function)
One might think the orthogonality is ultimately necessary. But I managed to show, after a lot of substitutions and simplifications, that, for $t,s>0$
$$\int_{-1}^1 \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{1-2xt+t^2}\sqrt{1-2xs+s^2}} = \frac{2}{\sqrt{st}}\operatorname{atanh}\sqrt{st}$$
from which not only the correct factor, but also orthogonality arises, since the result is a function of the product $st$ and not the variables alone. My question is: Is there some kind of clever substitution or some other shortcut how to show the identity above?
Note that an equivalent statement of the identity is
$$\int_{-1}^1 \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{1-2xt+t^2}\sqrt{1-2xs+s^2}} = \int_{-1}^1 \frac{\mathrm{d}z}{1-st \, z^2}$$
valid for all $t,s\in (-1,1)$.

Yes, this is the line of reasoning I used. The bounds are not -1 +1 anymore, and you need to compute this integral in terms of logaritms and plug in the bounds (1-t)/(1-s) and (1+t)/(1+s)

$$\frac1{\sqrt{1-2xt+t^2}\sqrt{1-2xs+s^2}}=\frac1{\sqrt{st}}\frac1{\sqrt{\frac{1-t^2}{2t}-x}}\frac1{\sqrt{\frac{1-s^2}{2s}-x}}$$
$$\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{a-x}\sqrt{b-x}}=-2\ln(\sqrt{a-x}+\sqrt{b-x})+C$$

@YvesDaoust The integral on the right is easy, of course. But you need to get to it by some substitution from the left.

Euler eventually leads to (assuming $s,t\neq0$ and $s\neq\pm1$)$$\int_{-1}^1\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1+t^2-2tx}\sqrt{1+s^2-2sx}}=\int_{\tfrac1t\cdot\tfrac{1-t}{1-s}}^{\tfrac1t\cdot\tfrac{1+t}{1+s}}\frac{dv}{1-st v^2}$$but the limits only agree with the target integral's if $st=1$...

$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-2x t+t^2}\sqrt{1-2x s+s^2}}=\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{st}}\frac 1 {\sqrt{x^2-a x+b }} $$ where
$$a=\frac{(s+t) (s t+1)}{2 s t}\qquad \text{and} \qquad b=\frac{\left(s^2+1\right)
   \left(t^2+1\right)}{4 s t}$$ Complete the square
$$\int  \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2-a x+b }}=-\log \left(2 \sqrt{x^2-a x+b+}-2
   x+a\right)$$
So, the definite integral is
$$\log \left(\frac{2 \sqrt{b+a+1}+a+2}{2\sqrt{b-a+1}+a-2}\right)$$ Replace $(a,b)$ by their value and use the logarithmic expression of the hyperbolic arctangent to obtain the solution.
